# Facebook Ads API managing own account rate limits

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

my question is simple, we need an app to manage a large amount of Facebook ads/adsets on our own single account.

Basic operations, like for example setting a daily budget for all adsets in one shot, instead of manually doing it via facebook interface.

The issue is that we are reaching the API limits pretty fast, as we can have even 50-100 adsets in one campaign. I am hitting the API limit simply by listing them sometimes.

I saw in the Facebook App advanced settings that you can add an Facebook Ad account ID, or a Business account, would that help with the limits?

Or even better, is this even possible? Handling large amount of ads? We have a big budget and all, but it's getting tedious to micromanage large amount of ads.

Answer (score 2):

The rate limit per adaccount is heavier limited if you are in development than in basics. In the basics level you can also have three instead of one system users, which would probably mean (correct me if I am wrong) that you can alternate between three tokens and thus get more api calls.

It is also worth to note that updating existing ads/adsets/campaigns is 10-100 times more expensive than creating new ones. You will also get the rate limit error if you change daily budget or similar more than four times a day, so that might be a problem during testing.